# Props not recognized by child node

Tags: typeerror, react-props, react-map-gl

```
   export default function Parent(){
     return(
            <Child items={array}/>
           )
   }
   export default function Child(props){
     return(
            {props.items.map(...)}
           )
   }
```

**OUTPUT: TypeError:props.items.map() is not a function

Can anyone explain??**

Comment: You should try to format the question a little better. Try to put the code like this -  ``` <Put your code here> ```.